# why next-translate library is in picture when next js supports internationalization out of the box?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I want to create a multi-lingual project , is it necessary to use next-translate with next js?

If we are not using next-translate, then do all the configs files related to language variables get shipped to browser in build

Comment: Next.js supports i18n _routing_, you still need to use a third-party library (like `next-translate`) to handle the translations.

Comment: @juliomalves But why do we need third-party when it is already supported in next ?

Comment: Next.js supports the routing part, not the translation of the contents. You don't have to use a third-party library if you don't want to, you can handle the translations yourself if you'd prefer.